# IntelliJ : How to setup variables in settings.xml?

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, ivy

I use `ivyIDEA` plugin in **IntelliJ IDE** and every thing is ok when I insert my username and password manually with their values in `ivysettings.xml` file.

**But** I try to make **username** and **password** are a variables in a file then read it in `xml`like this :

```
<credentials host="myhost" realm="Artifactory Realm"
             username="${file.USER}" passwd="${file.PASS}" />
```

where can I put these variables to make `ivysettings.xml` read it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

To read variables from file
let's say that file is named `file123.properties` and has the following content

```
myUser=actualUsername
myPassword=actualPassword
```

to use this file and it's variables in `ivysettings.xml`:

```
<properties file="file123.properties"/>
<credentials host="myhost" realm="Artifactory Realm" username="${myUser}" passwd="${myPassword}" />
```

Of course this implies that both files are on the same path.

---

To use directly in ivysettings.xml
Simply define them as properties

```
<property name="myUser" value="actualUsername" />
<property name="myPassword" value="actualPassword" />
<credentials host="myhost" realm="Artifactory Realm" username="${myUser}" passwd="${myPassword}" />
```

Comment: No, I want to define my values in file then read it on that xml file !

Comment: Sorry I don't understand... Also that doesn't seem to be what's written in the question. You want to have file (let's call it `file2.prop`) containing those variables and that `ivysettings.xml` read the values of variables from `file2.prop`?

Comment: Thank u , I edited my question. So, u can edit ur answer with simple example as u said to accept it plz..

Comment: my friends make it in eclipse using `.bat` file which that file can open eclipse with specific properties `set USER=name   eclipse.exe`

Comment: but this file must be there in each project I have. So, I want to setup these variables inside the Intellij IDE itself or external file as a standard for all project mentioned these variables.